# Eclipse CDT: Make a project rebuild when a library built in another project was rebuild

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

We have several C projects in Eclipse, using CDT (CodeSourcery++).

There are two projects that build libraries for use in the "main" project that builds the final application.

Now we find that rebuilding one of the libraries does not cause the main project to be also rebuild. Obviously, there is no dependency in the makefile to cause this.

The libraries themselves are linked in properly, but the final build result does not depend on them.

How can we create this dependency?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the CDT references page to specify the library configuration referenced by your main project.

```
Right click on Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths & Symbols > References
```

CDT will then ensure that the library project is built first, and will ensure that the main executable is re-linked when the dependent library changes.

Answer (score 2):

In Main project properties, there is Project References. check on the dependent project. By this way firstly dependant project builds, after than main project building process starts.

Comment: Right, but does not help with my problem. Build process starts, but since there is no dependency on the library in the Makefile, it finds nothing has to be rebuild. So I do not have an updated Main project.

Answer (score 1):

See this stack overflow item.

[Project dependency in Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728878/project-dependency-in-eclipse-cdt)

Refers to an open bug in Eclipse CDT.