# Project dependency in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using eclipse for the first time. I'm a seasoned VisualStudio user, so I'm trying to find similar functionality in eclipse. I have two projects, A and B. Project A spits out libA.a when it's done compiling. Project B links against libA.a. Here is my problem.

1. I compile project A then project B, everything is fine.
2. I make a code change to project A that requires a build of project A.
3. I try to build project B, but it states that no changes have been detected.

How do I make project B aware of the output of project A?? Currently I'm having to do a clean build of project B for it to re-link against libA.a.

Thanks.

EDIT: In my ProjectB->Path and Symbols->References tab, I have project A checked. This doesn't relink after project A is rebuilt.

Comment: To clarify, I'm talking about re-linking and not recompiling project B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can work around this problem by using the `touch` command.

In Eclipse, as part of C/C++ Build/Settings is the tab 'Build Steps'. In the pre-build steps command line, enter `touch filename`.

`filename` is any file in your application. This could be the file with `main()`. This could be a special file just for this workaround, `touchdummy.c`, which can be a tiny file, which compiles quickly.

When the application builds, even if you didn't change any sources, the `touch` command causes make to rebuild the application. If the library was rebuilt, then the application gets rebuilt with the new library.

One can read about how `touch` affects the date/time of the file here.
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html

Edit: The exact command in Eclipse would be touch `${ProjDirPath}/src/main.c`

Edit: This command should work, but it appears that if the 'main' project did not change, the pre-build step is not executed. Also the `touch` command causes eclipse to prompt to reload the file it touched. A large annoyance.

Answer (score 28):

Try the below settings:

1. Go to properties of  *Main Project* → *C/C++ General* → *Paths and Symbols* → *References*
2. Tick all the dependencies.

Comment: This almost worked for, I also had to go to Export Settings Page of library project and remove all the entries from the tabs there (Includes, Symbols, Libraries, Libraries Paths).
If this page (the Export Settings page) is missing, enable it under Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Property Page Settings.  
Got this information from: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_referenced_configs.htm

Comment: It works following the above steps.  But Eclipse generates a makefile that uses absolute paths. (e.g myExe: $(OBJS) /root/proj2/Release/libProj2.a).  Is there a way to make Eclipse generates relative paths, such as "../../proj2/Release/libProj2.a"?

Comment: a word of warning, this is very heavy handed operation. If you're setting up a new project, go for it, but if you have an existing project with lots of settings that work, take care when using this. Eclipse will update your linker path and settings (and probably lots of other things too) so if you decide to not use this afterwards, you'll find eclipse has removed a lot of your previously existing settings.

Answer (score 7):

You go into Project Properties of Project B, select Project References and make it reference (depend) on Project A.

Edit, appears to be a known [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=210248)

Comment: I did this. This allows project B to recompile Project A if it's out of date. If project B does not need to recompile, it will not re-link against project A's output if a new output is available.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse projects depend on each other by virtue of the checkbox in the project's properties (dependent projects?) which is how Eclipse decides which to build. You can set this yourself, but it's usually set when you change your Java build path.

Comment: I did this and Project B build project A. However, when project A is out of date, project B doesnt not link against project A's output since project B doesn't have to recompile. I'm just referring to linking and not compiling.

Answer (score 1):

By default at least with QNX C++ projects, it WILL NOT check for changes in other projects.
Right click on the project, and expand "check dependencies on/off"->"check user headers only"
It seems to work, roughly... 
It appears to do a makedepends on the code, and adds *.d files to the output folder which are simply depends file that list the header files.
Note: these do not appear to get regenerated, and get out of date - I do not know how to regenerate them.

Answer (score 0):

**For Project A (library):**

*Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>Build Steps>Post-build steps>* touch -m ${ProjDirPath}/source/build/build_updated.cpp

You should create folder "source/build" firstly and don't add in that folder any other files.

**For Project B:**

*Properties>Project References>* check Project A

*Properties>С/С++ General>Paths and Symbols>Source Location>Link Folder>Link to folder in the file system>* find and pick "source/build" folder which you created for project A before.