# Why doesn't exist a relink button in compilers?

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I work in Linux with c++, using eclipse. But i have worked with Visual Studio too. They haven't got (or at least I don´t know how to do it) a button to relink a project.

Example:

I have a big project (1), with hundreds of cpp. That project uses a small library (2) to do foo. If I change foo behavior, and compile it, generating a library, I need to clean the big proyect (1), re-compile, that links the external libraries (2) and works.

The problem is the big project doesn't change, but with hundreds of cpps, its compile time is about 5 min. 5 min is a small change in a second library.

Is possible to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when I need to do this in Visual Studio I delete the executable manually.

Comment: You can avoid it by just re-linking instead of cleaning and re-building. How to do that depends on your compiler.

Comment: `make` automatically detects when dependent libraries change (assuming your Makefile rules are sane)...it seems odd that Eclipse wouldn't do the same. How is the library set up in relation to the project?

Comment: I have a make file, but only work ok on windows, to generate a visual studio project, in eclipse don´t work

Comment: in Visual Studio, you can relink only. Right click on a project, then `Project Only / Link Only`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would generally use `make` with a `makefile` for this.

With this method, you can generate your own rules for building code, including bypassing compilation of lots of source files if you only thing needed is relinking.

For example, the `makefile`:

```
prog: main.o other.o makefile
    gcc -o prog main.o other.o

main.o: main.c makefile
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c

other.o: other.c makefile
    gcc -c -o other.o other.c
```

would not recompile `main.c` if the only file you changed was `other.c`. It would simply compile `other.c` to make `other.o`, then link `other.o` and `main.o` together to create `prog`.

That's generally how it's done in the "command line" world. It's likely that it's also how it's done behind the curtains in many IDEs as well, just hidden from you.

What you'll need to find out is why the dependency checking is not working as expected. Without further information on how your project is set up, it's a little hard to be definitive.

Comment: It is a good practice to make targets depend on the makefile as well, so that they get relinked and possibly recompiled when makefiles change.

Comment: @Maxim, I usually do that but I don't generally want to clog up the answer with unnecessary detail (I could also add `.c.o` rules and use `CFLAGS` variables rather than specific arguments for each rule). However, given how important that particular issue is, I'll make an exception for this case. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's sometimes good practice, but not always. Depends how you're going to use the makefile. If I add a brand new target, I don't actually need to rebuild the world, and the question assumes that doing so is "too slow" in some sense. Arguably it's more convenient just to be on me that when I change the makefile I should either `make -B` the targets I've changed or else `make (very)clean` if I'm not sure. It can be a bit tiresome if you fix a comment in your makefile (full rebuild), then check it in (another full rebuild if the file contains a version number).

Answer (score 5):

I suspect, but it is just a guess, your project is missing a *dependency* between your foo library and other deliverables in your project.

In this way, when you modify foo, the compiler does not know that it needs to recompile (as much as required by the change in foo) the rest of the project, and this forces you to manually clean and rebuild.

Usually a dependency is specified in a highly compiler-specific way, maybe this other [post from S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728878/project-dependency-in-eclipse-cdt) can help you, or just google "eclipse c++ dependency management".

Answer (score 0):

Add your static library under the Linker-Settings->Miscellaneous->Other objects. Your executable will just be relinked, in case the library is newer. No compilation.